# Svg to base64 without third party libraries c#

Tags: c#, .net, svg

I am trying to convert svg image URL to base 64, the problem is that i am limited and I can't use third party libraries in this project.
Is there any possible way to do that?

I've tried this but it did **not work**. Someone said that svg is a *file* **not** an image so `DownloadData` won't work right.

```
byte[] imageBytes;
string base64String = string.Empty;
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
     imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(appSuggestion?.IconUri.AbsoluteUri);
     base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
}
```

Any Idea what can I do?

**Edit:**
I wanted to use it in a data url `"data:image/svg+xml;base64,[base64String]"` in adaptive cards as an image url, at first I thought that adaptive cards are not supporting svg, but then I tried to write the url on chrome and it also didn't show the image.

Comment: So what didn't work? Did your computer crash or your fridge catch fire? Please be specific and read [ask]

Comment: You should ask the person who said that an SVG file is not an image for more information. They are correct that it's not a bitmap/raster image format like BMP, GIF, JPEG and PNG files. I guess the real question is why are you converting it base64 format? What are the format requirements of the thing you're feeding that base64 data to?

Comment: @TheGeneral  I've added an edit. please check it.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've added an edit explaining where I am using it. Could you please check it

Comment: are you sure the IconUri gives an svg and not an ico?

Comment: One possibility is you are getting a UTF-8 BOM character in the stream when you read it as binary data. You can read an SVG file as Text, then get the bytes using UTF8 encoding, then convert to base64. OR just use utf8 instead of base64 in your dataurl

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes, 
Here's the link to one of the icon urls : 
[link](https://shell.cdn.office.net/shellux/calendar_24x.102f9e31d85b6335f286b6850da33f4a.svg)

Edit: Will check your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Using `DownloadData` is perfectly valid here as it will return the content of the URI returned by the server as `byte[]`. The base64 conversion is also correct. What you've got so far will give you the base64-encoded content of any URI. I've just tested this and it works correctly.

Here's my test code to produce a `data:` URI from an SVG file hosted on a remote web server:

```
public string SVGUriToDataUri(Uri src)
{
    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(src);
        var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        return "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + {imageBase64};
    }
}
```

Putting the output of that into the address bar in Chrome displays the image as expected.

Here's a more general version that gets the mime type from the server:

```
public string DownloadAsDataUri(Uri src)
{
    using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
    {
        var imageBytes = wc.DownloadData(src);
        var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
        var mimeType = wc.ResponseHeaders["content-type"];
        if (mimeType.Contains(';'))
            mimeType = mimeType.Split(';')[0];
        return $"data:{mimeType};base64,{imageBase64}";
    }
}
```

If it's a PNG, BMP, ICO or whatever *and* it works when you put the URI itself then this should work. It works for me with the image link you posted - which is SVG.

If this does not work for then please post a copy of the output so we can investigate. At this point the only other option I can think of is that `appSuggestion?.IconUri.AbsoluteUri` is not giving you the correct address.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. 
when debugging I've checked the `appSuggestion?.IconUri.AbsoluteUri` and it's received as expected. I have also checked the data url again on chrome, and as u said it rendered just fine ("looks like I had a problem with the url before").
From My realization, I think it's a problem with MS Teams where I use adaptive cards. Cause adaptivecards supports svg images just fine